# NULL value not being validated in SQL

Tags: sql-server, validation, null

I have a table (TableA):

```
+-----+-------+----------+-----------+----------+
| ID  | Owner | Approval | Exception |   Type   |
+-----+-------+----------+-----------+----------+
| 200 | abc   | Approved | NULL      | Prepared |
+-----+-------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Where the column `Exception` can have `NULL, Denied, Returned` etc. I am trying to count the number of records based on some criteria and on the `NULL` values I am not getting right results.

My query is:

`SELECT CASE(WHEN Owner = 'abc' AND Approval = 'Approved' AND Exception <> 'Denied' AND Type = 'Prepared' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS prep1 FROM TableA WHERE ID = 200`

The above statement should return `1` but it's returning `0`. When I remove the criteria for the `Exception` column it returns the right result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the condition:

```
Exception <> 'Denied'
```

This should be:

```
ISNULL(Exception, '') <> 'Denied'
```

OR

```
AND (Exception IS NULL OR Exception <> 'Denied')
```

Note that when comparing to `NULL`, you should use the `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` keywords. Any other comparison made to `NULL` will result to UNKNOWN, which for the purpose of a `WHERE` clause or a `CASE` expression, is false. To illustrate, this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN NULL = 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END,
    CASE WHEN NULL <> 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END
```

will return :

```
----- -----
FALSE FALSE
```

For more info regarding `NULL`, read this [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-nulls-horribly-wrong-in-sql-server/) by Robert Sheldon.